# Time complexity variable

Tags: variables, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, notation

Can time complexity be expressed in terms of other variables or is it always expressed in n?

For example, instead of **O(n^2)**, I express the time complexity as **O(a^2)** since the recursive relation of a code uses **a** as the main variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can express complexity in terms of any variable name. Using n is as variable is general convention.